# Force shutdown doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

I have a DELL Insprion 15 laptop with Windows 10 installed.

Suddenly, while typing something, the keyboard stopped working. However, the mouse and the rest of Windows was working fine. To remedy the situation, I considered restarting the device.

Restart is initiated but stuck. I wanted to force shutdown by long pressing the power button. Even though I pressed it for +10 seconds several times, the computer did not shut down.

Currently, the computer still displays the "restarting" text with the blue screen. I am waiting for the computer to run out of battery. Normally it drains the battery very fast, but I guess the CPU and/or RAMs are not operational, i.e., it only powers the screen, so that it takes a long time for the battery to run out.

In case people are skeptical about whether I tried to force shutdown properly, here is a [video](https://youtu.be/02G9T8lxhbg) of what is going on.

What might be the causes of forced shutdown not working? I don't think I can avoid a trip to a technical service but still any help is appreciated.

Comment: The power button is a soft connection to the motherboard circuitry. A prolonged press should start the shutdown circuit. Failure to do so likely requires a repair.

Comment: @John So, do you think that the button is somehow disconnected? This also means that it won't start even if the battery runs out and I reconnect the charger, right? Is there any possible danger to the computer of letting the battery to run out?

Comment: It could be disconnected or there could be a circuitry error. Either way, you probably need to take it to a local shop.

Comment: @John Weirdly the computer now started up after I let the battery to drain to cause a shutdown. No data is lost. I am currently backing everything up. Then, I will try the force shutdown again. Apparently, the button is alright, maybe the circuitry that was supposed to handle the force shutdown is disconnected.

Comment: There definitely appears to be some sort of fault with the button.